# Authentication in nextJS: passport.js or next-auth

Tags: authentication, next.js, passport.js, next-auth

I currently building in next.js. I am coming from a MEAN app where I was using passport.js for authentication.

I have seen that in NextJs I can still use passport.js or next-auth.

I am wondering what are the pros of cons of using one over the other. And is there one "more suitable" for next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since next-auth is designed specifically for next.js, that one would be more suitable.

Comment: I understand, but I wanted to use 'sign in with telegram' so I have decided to go with passport. Next-auth does not support that. On the Angular issue I am sorry. I did not know better! Now I have seen the light. :)